# Where in my application do I define the worklightServerRootURL element for my Worklight 6.1 Server running on PureApplication System?

Tags: worklight-studio, worklight-server

I migrated my application from Worklight 5.0.6 to 6.1. I tested the application in Worklight Studio 6.1 in the local Liberty Test server and Mobile Browser Simulator and the application works fine. I have now deployed my Worklight Server 6.1 on PureApplication System using Mobile Application Platform Pattern 6.1.

In Worklight 6.1 the worklightServerRootURL element that existed in application-descriptor.xml has been removed. In Worklight 5.0.6 I defined the IP address of my Worklight Server running on PureApplication System in the worklightServerRootURL element. With this element removed in 6.1 where do I define the IP address of my worklight server runing on PureApplication System in my application so my application can talk to the Worklight server on PureApplication System ?

Answer (score 0):

Run As -> Build Settings and Deploy Target;  Then add a new server other than the localhost.

http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.worklight.dev.doc%2Fdev%2Fc_building_and_deploying_build_settings_deploy_target.html